# How to use odata filter on field not present in the result set

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata

Let's say I have a model with the following properties: ID, First Name, LastName.

I would like to ask if it is possible to create an odata v4 controller and request a filter with a field that is not present in the result set, for example "Address". So something like this $filter=startswith(address, 'foobar') eq true

The backend will be responsible to do the appropriate inner joins from whatever table that is, in order to return me the appropriate data.

Is this possible only with $filter query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ODataQueryOptions<TEntity>` as your action method's parameter specifying the entity type that contains the properties on which you'd like to filter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnet.odata.query.odataqueryoptions-1?view=odata-aspnetcore-7.0